# How do I collapse these tables individually?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple tables each nested in its own div tag. When I try to close just one table they all close.
HTML:

```
<div>
<p>Table Title</p>
<table>
table content
</table>
</div>

<div>
<p>Table Two Title</p>
<table>
table content
</table>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $("p").click(function(){
    $("table").slideToggle("fast");
    });
</script>
```

The HTML looks legit, new to Jquery so the problem might be in that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` to get the clicked `p` tag and then select the `table` using `.next` function.

```js
$("p").click(function() {
  $(this).next("table").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

```css
table { display:  block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>Table Title</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>table content</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Table Two Title</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>table content</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not right.

```
$("table") //select all the table
```

Try this :

```
$("p").click(function(){
    $(this).next("table").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $("p").click(function(){
    var self = $(this); //for speed and OBJECT this placement
    //get the table
    var table_to_toggle = self.next(); //by your HTML the next DOM element should be the table.
    table_to_toggle.slideToggle("fast");
});
</script>
```

---

So you need to access the table related to the "p" tag you chose. Then close that table.
I used .next() to grab the next DOM node in the DOM tree structure. Then you can manipulate the DOM element you want instead of ALL of the table elements.

Note **

```
$("table")
```

selects ALL the tables in the DOM.

```
console.log($("table").size());
```

This will tell you how many tables were selected

Go into your console under Developer Tools and put this inside your console.

```
$("table")
```

It will print out all of the tables. Then you can hover over each one and see what was selected. It is a good way to test your jQuery before you commit the code.

Comment: jQuery has `.size` function? I think you mean the `.length` property. (jQuery had size function, but deprecated long back http://api.jquery.com/size/)